# elegant way to redirect with array in GrailsParameterMap groovy

Tags: grails, groovy

Is there any elegant way to redirect with the array in GrailsParameterMap?

When I type:

`redirect(action: "XXX", params: params)`

I get array which looks like *[Ljava.lang.String;@596a40f1*

EDIT: I have more precisely defined my question.

Comment: `params` must be a map with name&value for each parameter. what do you have in your array?

Comment: params: [cId:[1, 16, 18]]

Comment: convert is to list

Comment: "I get array which looks like [Ljava.lang.String;@596a40f1" - That is the output of the `toString()` method on an array.  Are you saying that String (`[Ljava.lang.String;@596a40f1`) is in the array, or is that just what you see when you print the value?

Answer (score 1):

'params' are accessible by ALL controllers/Interceptors when redirecting. The one thing to keep in mind is that a redirect issues a NEW request/response so the headers can be different from the original request you got...99% of the time they will NOT BE! But this is something to keep in mind.

Also if, you need 'params' in spring filter, you just have to manually parse the request yourself.

But as 'params' are merely the request parameters, they are available to all components that have access to the request. :)

Hope that answers the question.

Answer (score 1):

to pass an array of values into one parameter you have to convert this array to ArrayList

example:

```
//String.split() returns as array of strings
//as List - converts array to a List
params=[cId: "1,16,18".split(',') as List]
```

you could convert `params.cId` parameter to a List just before redirect

```
params.cId = params.cId as List
redirect(action: "XXX", params: params)
```